# Grails Namespace problems

Tags: grails

I'm having problems with grails redirecting to namespaces:

I have this redirect in a LoginController:

```
redirect(namespace:'auth',controller:'login',action: "login")
```

and this defined in my URL Mappings:

```
"/auth/$action?/$id?" {
 controller = 'login'
 namespace = 'auth'
 }
```

However the redirect does not work, it redirects: login/login rather than auth/login.

Also the login form is generated with a action of login/authenticate rather than auth/authenticate.

Any ideas?

This is Grails 2.3.4 btw.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that has worked for me was to use a [named URL Mapping](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/guide/single.html#namedMappings):

1) provide a mapping name in your UrlMappings.groovy:

```
name specialLoginMapping: "/auth/$action?/$id?" {
 controller = 'login'
 namespace = 'auth'
}
```

2) reference this mapping in your redirect call

```
redirect(mapping: 'specialLoginMapping', action: 'login')
```

Grails should take the controller/namespace from the above UrlMappings entry

Answer (score 0):

Try it with these codes in your UrlMappings.groovy:

```
"/auth/$controller/$action?/$id?" {
   namespace = 'auth'
}
```

To get the proper path of the controller in the form action, use namespace in url:

```
<g:form url="[action:'save', namespace:'auth']">
.......
</g:form>
```